# Writing to a linked lists with nested structs

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to write a function that can read some info from a file into a node in a doubly linked list. The format for the each nodes data is as follows.

struct(named record)
artist
album
song
genre
songLength(This is another struct that contains mins and secs)
playcount
rating

```
void load(FILE *file, Node *head)
{
    char tempArtist='\0', tempAlbum='\0', tempTitle='\0', tempGenre='\0'
    ,tempSpace='\0',tempMins='\0',tempSecs='\0';
    SongLength *tempLength=NULL;
    int tempPlay=0, tempRating=0,test=0;
tempLength = (SongLength*)malloc(sizeof(SongLength));

    fscanf(file,"%s",&tempArtist);
    fscanf(file,"%s",&tempAlbum);
    fscanf(file,"%s",&tempTitle);
    fscanf(file,"%s",&tempGenre);
    fscanf(file,"%s",&tempMins);
    fscanf(file,"%s",&tempSecs);
    fscanf(file,"%s",&tempPlay);
    fscanf(file,"%s",&tempRating);
    fscanf(file,"%s",&tempSpace);

    tempLength->mins=tempMins; 
    tempLength->secs=tempSecs;

    head->data->album=tempAlbum; // breaks here
    head->data->artist=tempArtist;
    head->data->genre=tempGenre;
    head->data->song=tempTitle;
    head->data->length=tempLength;
    head->data->played=tempPlay;
    head->data->rating=tempRating;

}
```

This is my current load function. When attempting to store these values in to nodes data I get an access violation.

Here are my structs for easy reproduction

```
typedef struct songlength
{
    int mins;
    int secs;
}SongLength;


typedef struct record
{
    char artist;
    char album;
    char song;
    char genre;
    struct songlength *length;
    int played;
    int rating;

}Record;

typedef struct node
{
    struct node *pPrev;
    struct node *pNext;
    struct record *data;

}Node;
```

---

makeNode

```
Node *makeNode(Record *newData)
{
    Node *temp = NULL;

    temp=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));

    temp->data=newData;
    temp->pNext=NULL;

    return temp;
}
```

If any confusion arises just let me know!
Also this is my first experience with dynamic memory so be gentle :P

Thanks!

Comment: When you are using dynamic memory you need to explicitly ``malloc`` it. You have a problem as you declare ``tempLength`` as a pointer and then never allocate any memory for it.

Comment: @SimonGibbons Would the memory not already be allocated when I initialize a head node? (happens in main)

Comment: Yes possibly (but I can't see that code) however when you do ``tempLength->mins=tempMins;`` you are using ``tempLength`` which doesn't know anything about any memory you have previously allocated for that structure.

Comment: So how would I go about allocating memory for my node? Since within node there is another struct, record.

I'll include my make node function above.

Answer (score 2):

These lines are not right.

```
fscanf(file,"%s",&tempArtist);
fscanf(file,"%s",&tempAlbum);
fscanf(file,"%s",&tempTitle);
fscanf(file,"%s",&tempGenre);
fscanf(file,"%s",&tempMins);
fscanf(file,"%s",&tempSecs);
fscanf(file,"%s",&tempPlay);
fscanf(file,"%s",&tempRating);
fscanf(file,"%s",&tempSpace);
```

They will definitely lead to undefined behavior because of the way the variables are defined.

You cannot expect

```
char c = '\0';
fscanf(file, "%s", &c);
```

to work. There isn't enough memory at `&c` to read a string. You need something like:

```
char s[100]; // Or some size that is large enough to hold the data
             // you are about to read.
fscanf(file, "%99s", s); // Make sure that you don't read more than 99
                         // characters. Leave at least one character
                         // for the terminating null character.
```

I hope that gives you enough clues on how to change your variables.

Answer (score 1):

You did not assign memory for the variable `tempLength` to point to.

Add this before accessing the elements

```
SongLength *tempLength = malloc(sizeof(struct(SongLength));
```

**EDIT**

I'm just giving an overall idea how to allocate and use nested structs for your case

```
Node *head;
Record *r=malloc(sizeof(struct record));
SongLength *s=malloc(sizeof(struct songlength));
r->length=s;//<----- 1
r->length->mins=10;//Now you can assign values

head=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
head->pPrev=NULL;
head->pNext=NULL;
head->data=r;//<--- The length member inside record is already assigned memory in 1

head->data->artist='c';
head->data->length->mins=10;//assign
```

Comment: This work, but it then proceeded to break when trying to assign  the scanned data to the node. Would I also need to malloc each one of the temp variables i made?

Comment: @user348104 You must allocate memory for `songlength` inside `record` before you pass it to `makeNode`

Comment: `char` can hold only `one character`. You must use an array as sahu's answer states